# Pasar información de una ventana a otra con window.open de JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una página padre.html que tiene dos títulos (h2) y dos botones (button) y me gustaría que, al darle al botón 1, se abra la página hijo.html y muestre el título 1 y al darle al botón 2, se abra la página hijo.html y muestre el título 2, pero no se cómo pasar esa información de la página padre.html a la página hijo.html. ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano?

Este es es el código de la página padre.html:

```js
const titulos = document.querySelectorAll(".titulo");
        const botones = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

        botones.forEach((boton, i) => {
            boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                window.open("hijo.html", "_self");
            })
        })
```

```css
body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
            gap: 5rem;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="info">
        <h2 class="titulo">TITULO 1</h2>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Enviar título</button>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h2 class="titulo">TITULO 2</h2>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Enviar título</button>
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Y este otro el de la página hijo.html

```css
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>RECUPERAR TÍTULO DE LA PÁGINA PADRE</h1>
    <h2 id="titulo"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías enviar parámetros de una página a otra mediante variables GET o POST, ambos te sirven.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes mandar esa información como parte de la URL:

```js
const titulos = document.querySelectorAll(".titulo");
        const botones = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

        botones.forEach((boton, i) => {
            boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log("Enviando título", boton.dataset.title);
                window.open(`hijo.html?title=${boton.dataset.title}`, "_self");
            })
        })
```

```css
body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
            gap: 5rem;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="info">
        <h2 class="titulo">TITULO 1</h2>
        <button type="submit" class="button" data-title="TITULO 1">Enviar título</button>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h2 class="titulo">TITULO 2</h2>
        <button type="submit" class="button" data-title="TITULO 2">Enviar título</button>
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Y en la página hija puedes recuperar ese valor usando

```javascript
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
document.getElementById("titulo").innerHtml=urlParams.get("title");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Finalmente he conseguido que funcione.